# Can't Instantiate Map...well why not?

Tags: java, instantiation

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>>> k = new  Map<String, ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>>>();
```

This line is in my code. I'd like to instantiate a Map that contains a String then an ArrayList of Pairs of Strings and Integers.

Pair is a class that I wrote that is in my package.

I get "Cannot Instantiate the type Map>>();

Why not? Seems reasonable to me...

Comment: What is `Map`..? A class, an interface, an enum?

Comment: The built-in `Map` is an interface.  Choose an implementing concrete class on the right side.

Comment: Can you intantiate an interface ??

Comment: To make it shorter, you can use the diamond operator `<>`. Java can infer the type arguments: `Map<String, List<Pair<String, Integer>>> k = new  HashMap<>();` And please use the interface instead the concrete type to declare your variable. This enables you, to alter the implementation at only one point of your source code.

Comment: This object, by the way, is a map that uses a string as a key that points to a value that is a list of string and integer Pairs...  I recommend writing it as a cohesive java object rather than a jumble of simple types.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The built-in `Map` is an interface, which cannot be instantiated.  You can choose between lots of implementing concrete classes on the right side of your assignment, such as:

- `ConcurrentHashMap`
- `HashMap`
- `LinkedHashMap`
- `TreeMap`

and many others.  The [Javadocs for `Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) lists many direct concrete implementations.

Comment: You helped me alot, thank you so much my man :^)

Answer (score 11):

Interfaces cant be intantiated
You need to use some concrete class implementing the interface
Try something like this

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>>> k = new  HashMap<String, ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>>>();
```